# Durandal 2.0 Modal using IFrame to display HTML file content

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog, durandal, durandal-2.0

I am currently using Durandal 2.0 to produce a modal dialog box to display an HTML file.  I am successfully doing it using IFRAME tag.  Its needed for the application.  SSRS produces these files daily and the user needs to see the content of these files on an intranet app.  I was wondering is there a more preferred way of displaying the content of an external HTML file other than using IFRAME tags or is IFRAME tags are still the preferred way?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML views has nothing to do with your view models then I think there is  no point of making that HTML files to a Durandal view.
 Because the actions/navigations happening in those HTML files are independent from your Durandal application it is better to use an IFrame.